# ¿Cómo extraigo todos los elementos de una lista hasta uno determinado?

Tags: python, lista

Tengo una lista la cual quiero importar a otra siempre y cuando se cumpla una condición, por ejemplo

```
lista=['versa','attitude','beat','MERCADO','tornado']
```

Quiero hacer dos cosas. La primera es  llegar a la siguiente lista:

```
lista1=['versa','attitude','beat']
```

es decir que deje de importar hasta encontrar la palabra MERCADO

y la siguiente lista

```
lista2=['versa','attitude','beat','tornado']
```

es decir que me importe todo menos la palabra MERCADO

```
for c in lista:
  count=True
  while True:
    if c.starswith('MERCADO)==True:
      break
  lista1.append(c)
```

Sin embargo no se que estoy haciendo mal, segun yo la instruccion es mas o menos la misma para lista2

Answer (score 1):

Definiremos una función que recibe una lista y una palabra de corte, devolviendo dos listas de acuerdo con lo solicitado: `lista_previa` con todas las palabras hasta la palabra de corte, y `lista_excluida`, con todas las palabras menos la palabra de corte.

Usaremos la variable `found`, que sera `True` cuando se encuentra la primera palabra de lista que coincida con la `palabra_corte`, para discriminar a que lista debe ir cada palabra.

Luego recorremos todas las palabras de la lista. Cuando encontramos la `palabra_corte`, nos saltamos esa palabra. Todas las restantes palabras son copiadas a la `lista_excluida`, pero sólo se copian a la `lista_previa` mientras no se encuentre la `palabra_corte`.

```
def separar(lista, palabra_corte):
    lista_previa = []   # Palabras de la lista hasta palabra_corte
    lista_excluida = [] # Toda la lista, menos palabra_corte
    found = False  # Indica si se ha encontrado la palabra_corte
    
    for word in lista:
        if word == palabra_corte:
            found = True
        else:
            lista_excluida.append(word) # Incluir aqui todas las palabras.
            if not found:
                lista_previa.append(word) # Dejar de agregar al encontrar palabra_corte.

    return lista_previa, lista_excluida
```

**Demo**

```
lista=['versa','attitude','beat','MERCADO','tornado']
lista_previa, lista_excluida = separar(lista, "MERCADO")
print(lista_previa)
print(lista_excluida)
```

produce:

```
['versa', 'attitude', 'beat']
['versa', 'attitude', 'beat', 'tornado']
```

Answer (score -2):

```
n=0
while lista[n].startswith('MERCADO')!=True:
n+=1
print(lista[n-1])
```

Comment: Un código sin explicación es como una acto de magia: algo funciona, pero no se sabe porque. Una respuesta debe explicar, enseñar e ilustrar.

Comment: Ademas la indentacion es incorrecta

Comment: Hola buen día,  agradezco tanto tus comentarios como la ayuda. Solo he realizado 2 preguntas por este medio, pero de aquí en adelante aterrizar más mi pregunta y cuidare el contexto. De nuevo muchas gracias

Comment: Esto es una respuesta o que es? fue reportada como de baja calidad, y no entiendo que es...

Comment: Si no entiendes nada adicional aportas con ese comentario.

Comment: Creo que eso no suena muy amistoso. Te estoy preguntando porque como moderador esta respuesta fue reportada de baja calidad, y puede ser eliminada si sigue recibiendo votos negativos. Si es una respuesta, por favor mira [answer]. Se pide que las respuestas no sea solo codigo, si no que expliquen la solucion. Tambien te recomendaria leer el [tour]... se mas cordial con quienes tratan de ayudarte.